# Tooltip partially obscured by outer div

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I would like to display a tooltip with item name when user hover over the image item. The items are shown inside a grid with scrollbar (class="itemGrid" and item itself is class="itemOnGrid").

I've tried many solutions over the internet, however I'm learning about CSS now and I could not solve my problem.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>TIBIA SET BUILDER</h1>
        <div id='instructions'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae varius lorem. Sed in volutpat orci, id placerat neque. <br>
                Nullam ipsum ante, maximus et scelerisque vel, auctor a elit. Nullam neque arcu, venenatis vel elit a, pharetra interdum ipsum.<br> 
                Aenean nisi sapien, ultricies id mollis ut, sagittis ac erat. Fusce id augue tempus, volutpat orci nec, pretium lectus. Fusce eu diam eros. 
                Donec hendrerit mattis eros, sed aliquam justo. Duis et fermentum sapien. Duis finibus sem vel augue facilisis ornare.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='menu'></div>
            <div class='items'>
                <input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Soulstrider, Abyss Hammer, etc...">
                <div class='itemGrid' id='scrollbarItems'>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a><span class="tooltiptext">Giant Sword</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='sets'></div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    /*background: linear-gradient(#252526, #1e1e1e);*/
    background: url(img/wp_soulwar.jpg);
    height: 1000px;
    align-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #d2b90a;
}

#instructions {
    width:1588px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.90);; 
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 20px;
    width:1600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu {
    order: 1;
    width:248px;
    height:598px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.90);
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.items {
    order: 2;
    width:578px;
    height:573px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.9);
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#searchBox{
    float: left;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: gray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(img/loupe.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 3px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color:  rgb(24,25,25);
    border: gray solid 1px;
}

.itemGrid {
    margin-top: 6px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width:568px;
    height:545px;
    background:transparent; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.itemGrid:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.itemOnGrid{
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: gray solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: rgb(24,25,25);
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.itemOnGrid .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    border: gray 1px solid;
}

.itemOnGrid .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  }

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.itemOnGrid:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

The items are added by JS, I wrote down 3 examples hard-coded.

Image of tooltip being cutted off:

[image: Image of tooltip being cutted off]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, that in your situation you can not solve it with css alone.
Since `overflow:hidden` cuts off everything outside of it.
You could probably remove `position:relative` from `itemOnGrid` class, but all your tooltips would end up in the same place - I really doubt you want to manually position all of them.
My solution is to use javascript for tooltip location(and also change its text).
I did change the placement of your elements a little, also edited the css accordingly for the new view.
The copies of the elements are just for demonstration purposes.

Now the solution is basically this function `prepare` where I assign eventListeners to every `itemOnGrid`. In this eventListener I read the position of the element that has been hovered and move (and change text of) the tooltip. I didn't really care about perfect location of the tooltip here, so you might want to play with it a little.

```js
function prepare(){
        let items = document.getElementsByClassName('itemOnGrid');
        for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            items[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){          
                let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
                let top = this.offsetTop;
                let left = this.offsetLeft;
                
                tooltip.style.top = top-30+'px';
                tooltip.style.left = left-35+'px';
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
                tooltip.innerText = this.getAttribute('itemName');
            });
            items[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
                let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
                tooltip.style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
    };
```

```css
body {
    /*background: linear-gradient(#252526, #1e1e1e);*/
    background: url(img/wp_soulwar.jpg);
    height: 1000px;
    align-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #d2b90a;
}

#instructions {
    width:1588px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.90);; 
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 20px;
    width:1600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu {
    order: 1;
    width:248px;
    height:598px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.90);
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.items {
    order: 2;
    width:578px;
    height:573px;
    background-color:rgb(24,25,25,0.9);
    border:solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#searchBox{
    float: left;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: gray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(img/loupe.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 3px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color:  rgb(24,25,25);
    border: gray solid 1px;
}

.itemGrid {
    margin-top: 6px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width:568px;
    height:545px;
    background:transparent; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.itemGrid:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.itemOnGrid{
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: gray solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: rgb(24,25,25);
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

/* Tooltip text */
 .tooltiptext {
    display:none;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    border: gray 1px solid;
}

 .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  }
```

```html
<body onload="prepare()">
    <center>
        <h1>TIBIA SET BUILDER</h1>
        <div id='instructions'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae varius lorem. Sed in volutpat orci, id placerat neque. <br>
                Nullam ipsum ante, maximus et scelerisque vel, auctor a elit. Nullam neque arcu, venenatis vel elit a, pharetra interdum ipsum.<br> 
                Aenean nisi sapien, ultricies id mollis ut, sagittis ac erat. Fusce id augue tempus, volutpat orci nec, pretium lectus. Fusce eu diam eros. 
                Donec hendrerit mattis eros, sed aliquam justo. Duis et fermentum sapien. Duis finibus sem vel augue facilisis ornare.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='menu'></div>
            <div class='items'>
                <input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Soulstrider, Abyss Hammer, etc...">
                <div class='itemGrid' id='scrollbarItems'>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword1><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword2><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword3><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword4><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword5><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword6><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword7><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword1><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword2><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword3><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword4><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword5><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword6><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                <div class="itemOnGrid" itemName=Giant_Sword7><a href=''><img src=Giant_Sword.gif></a></div>
                </div>
                <span id='tooltip' class="tooltiptext">Giant Sword</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class='sets'></div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Jay, it works perfectly! I have no words to describe how grateful I'm, thanks so much! I loved your solution, there is no problem with javascript solution, actually I'm learning web development and started from html and css, I studied your code and got what it does. Again thank you!

Comment: And Jay, have you notice when page is loaded an empty tooltip are loaded on .sets div? If I move my cursor on itemsOnGrid it dissapears, is possible remove it using js as well? thanks again! :)

Comment: My bad, forgot to add `display:none` to the `.tooltip` css - it should've been there from the start =)
For testing purposes I left it visible at all times and then forgot to make it invisible